# while loop with dynamic list in python using a dictionnary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with lots of data from a CSV file where the key is the row number and the value is a list that contains the column data.

What I want to do is to check from a data of each line (key) and from column 2, I take its data from column 4 and then look for this data in column 2 of another line (key) and take its data in column 4 and continue until it finds the last value of column 4 in column 2.

My code is this:

```
dict_FH_coord = self.dict_FH() 
site_SI='some_site'       
list_test = [site_SI]

while len(list_test) > 0:
    for ele in list_test:
        for cle, val in dict_FH_coord.items():
            list_test = []
            if val[2] == ele:
                list_test.append(val[4])
                list_def.append(val)
                print(val)
```

But this code does not work because it stops at the first iteration and it finds that the elements linked to the starting `site_SI` only

Is there a way to do successive iterations with the list `list_test` which becomes dynamic to solve my problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without knowing what `dict_FH` looks like.  Can you provide example data?  That said, I'm guessing what's going on is `list_test = []`  is clearing out the list before you've completely gone through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify list '*on air*' you sohuld do something like

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[:] = [1, 2]
```

In your case the only way you may use this inside the loop (avoiding infinite list size increasement):

```
if val[2] == ele:
    list_test[:] = list_test[1:]+[val[4]]
    list_def.append(val)
else:
    list_test[:] = list_test[1:]
```

But it wont work as intended because previous iteration ends at index 1 (`for ele in list_test:`), and `list_test` would never change in size.

Both this cases can not be merged with each other.

I suggest you to use `Queue`, but be careful to avoid infinite links looping inside your data:

```
from queue import Queue
dict_FH_coord = {
    1: [0, 1, 'some_site', 3, 'some_site_2'],
    2: [0, 1, 'some_site_2', 3, 'some_site_3'],
    3: [0, 1, 'some_site_2', 3, 'some_site_4'],
    4: [0, 1, 'some_site_3', 3, 'some_site_5'],
}
site_SI = 'some_site'
unvisited = Queue()
unvisited.put(site_SI)
list_def = list()
while not unvisited.empty():
    ele = unvisited.get()
    for cle, val in dict_FH_coord.items():
        if val[2] == ele:
            unvisited.put(val[4])
            list_def.append(val)
            print(val)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's excatly what I want and works for me :) ;)